# Allowed parents and Allowed children property in CQ template

Tags: aem

What is the purpose of allowed parents and allowed children property while creating a cq template?
The description in [documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/developing/components.html) simply says "Path of a component that is allowed to be a parent of this component"/"Path of a component that is allowed to be a child of this component".
What is the importance of these properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These properties allows you to set some contract of structure of pages in you project.
For example:
you have 3 templates (and corresponding pages with this templates):

- template-1: allowedChildren="[template-2]"
- template-2: allowedChildren="[template-3]"
- template-3: allowedChildren="[]"

Then in siteadmin, you will be able to create:

- under page with template "template-1" only pages with template "template-2",
- under page with template "template-2" only pages with template "template-3",
- under page with template "template-3" you will not be able to create any page.

Comment: Thanks Alex!! Now about allowedParents property.. If template-1:allowedparent="[template2]" does that mean page using template1 can only be created as child page of page created using template2?

Comment: @Jai I suggest you read next article - http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/templates.html#Template%20Availability . CQ has pretty sophisticated mechanism of templates availability.